# Advanced TypeScript argument constraints

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if somethings as follows is possible in TypeScript, 
What I'm trying to achieve:

1. If the `type` is `inbox` then `obj` should be of type interface `IInbox`.
2. If the `type` is `sent` then `obj` should be of type interface `ISent`.

---

```
interface IInbox {

}

interface ISent {

}

class MailClient {
    delete(type: "inbox" | "sent", obj: IInbox | ISent) {

    }
}

let client = new MailClient();
client.delete('inbox', <ISent>{}); // should give compile error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define multiple signatures:

```
class MailClient {
    delete(type: "inbox", obj: IInbox);
    delete(type: "sent", obj: ISent)
    delete(type: "inbox" | "sent", obj: IInbox | ISent) {}
}
```

But that still won't have a compilation error because your interfaces are identical.
Because typescript is using [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) then the empty object (`{}`) satisfies the type requirements.
If you differentiate between the two:

```
interface IInbox {
    a: string;
}

interface ISent {
    b: string;
}
```

Then you get your error:

```
client.delete('inbox', {} as ISent); // Argument of type '"inbox"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"sent"'
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IInbox%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ISent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MailClient%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20delete(type%3A%20%22inbox%22%2C%20obj%3A%20IInbox)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20delete(type%3A%20%22sent%22%2C%20obj%3A%20ISent)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20delete(type%3A%20%22inbox%22%20%7C%20%22sent%22%2C%20obj%3A%20IInbox%20%7C%20ISent)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20client%20%3D%20new%20MailClient()%3B%0D%0Aclient.delete('inbox'%2C%20%7B%7D%20as%20ISent)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Argument%20of%20type%20'%22inbox%22'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'%22sent%22'))

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this constraint is not possible, anyway you can easily write a very simple workaround as following:

```
class MailClient {
    delete(type: "inbox" | "sent", objI?: IInbox, objS?: ISent) {
        if ((type === "inbox" && typeof objS !== "undefined") ||
                 type === "send" && typeof objI !== "undefined") {
            throw new "Invalid parameter";    
        }
        let obj = (type === "inbox") ? objI : objS;
    }
}
```

This would do your job in a quite readable way.